# Compiled NodeJS project won't run after adding prisma

Tags: node.js, node-modules, prisma

My NodeJS project used to run fine after being compiled into an executable,
but after replacing my previous ORM with Prisma, although it is being compiled successfully when I try to run the executable, my app is working until it loads Prisma then I get this error:

```
/snapshot/daemon/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:25789
          throw new PrismaClientInitializationError(
                ^

PrismaClientInitializationError: Unable to load Node-API Library from /snapshot/daemon/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node, Library may be corrupt
    at DefaultLibraryLoader.loadLibrary (/snapshot/daemon/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:25789:17)
    at async LibraryEngine.loadEngine (/snapshot/daemon/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:26093:24)
    at async LibraryEngine.instantiateLibrary (/snapshot/daemon/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:26051:5) {
  clientVersion: '4.3.1',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

Note: The project is running fine without compiling after adding Prisma.

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: How do you "compile into an executable"?

Comment: Using vercel pkg.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: Tried with multiple versions of node: 14, 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use pkg 5.3.0 and add:

```
{
  "pkg": {
    "assets": ["node_modules/.prisma/client/*.node"]
  }
}
```

To `package.json`